# Can I TrueCrypt half of a dual booted machine?

Tags: multi-boot, truecrypt

I want to have two copies of Windows 7 installed on the same physical drive, is it possible to use TrueCrypt to encrypt one of the drive partitions/windows instances?

If so, how should I go about it, (i.e. what order to install things from scratch)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The links will detail all you require to setup both the dual boot and encryption of partition. You should read the links a couple of times and you should run a backup, clone or just save data before you start - just in case - if you do not have a favorite clone software Clonezilla will do the job.

- [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)
- [To dual boot two win7s on same drive](http://thpc.info/dual/win7/dualboot_win7+7_on_win7.html)

Steps:

1. Fully install the first Windows 7 (Win7. a), then go to:

   Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management and shrink the' C: volume ' to the size required

   Make it an unallocated partition (you can run a clone of the hard drive at this time, just in case).
2. Turn off all programs and shut down the computer in the correct manner.
3. Fully install the second Windows 7 (Win7. b) selecting the newly unallocated partition for the second Win7 install.
4. Shut down in the correct manner and test both Win7.a and Win7.b, to insure all is OK (you can run a clone of full hard drive at this point-just in case).
5. Select the Win7 install you wish to encrypt, load and open Truecrypt and start the encryption.

   - [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)
   - [Beginner's Tutorial](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-encryption)

   At the 3rd step of Truecrypt you will be asked by the Truecrypt Install Wizard to select the type of encryption you wish to use:

   1. a container placed in a folder
   2. a non-system partition
   3. a partition or whole system drive

   The 3rd option is what you need to use for your goal (you can select to have this partition hidden).
6. Follow the Truecrypt Install Wizard and encrypt your Windows 7 install. Don't forget to read the links and write down your passwords.